# Moorangri Topic Archive (mystery)

Tags: steganography, situation

[image]

It is a mystery for you and your flipped boots...where is the light switch?

Moorangri is in the international archive of Internet...as a subject.

Comment: Lighten it up...

Comment: Lightening up the image doesn't work, and neither does saturation or gamma. (helpful someone here)

Comment: I can see words, though not by lightening it up.  they're hard to read, but "Good Luck" is pretty clear and it may be signed by Amy?  Is this part of some contest?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I lightened up the image and saw Misc Practice.

Comment: How exactly did you "lighten up the image"? Were did you see "Misc Practice"?

Comment: You can put solutions inside a spoiler tag by prefacing the line with ">!". That way, other people can solve the puzzle without seeing your solution.

Comment: I don't understand how he lightened it up. I lightened it up and used saturation/gamma there.

Comment: @someoneinexistence [Shotwell, on an Ubuntu 20.04.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjfYk.png) Took about 60 seconds, but I think bad wording on the part of the OP had something to do with people's confusion. That said, the writing is still difficult to read, and I don't know what "Misc Practice" means.

Comment: It’s my YouTube channel.